# How to make a multidimensional SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, tensor-products, svd

Is it possible to define a tensor Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)?

For example for the 3 tensor
$$\left[\begin{array}{rr}1&-1\\1&1\\\hline 1&-1\\-1&-1\end{array}\right]$$

Can be written as a linear combination (in octave code)

```
[1,-1].*[1;0].*cat(3,1,1) + [1,1].*[0;1].*cat(3,1,-1)
```

The rank 1 tensors which we make outer product between are pairwise orthogonal in each direction [1,-1] against [1,1], [1;0] against [0;1] and 1,1 against 1,-1 in the third dimension.

Is this a reasonable generalization of the SVD in some sense or am I thinking wrongly?

Comment: If you're generally interested in $p \times p \times 2$ tensors, you should find the [results discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3475399/81360) to be useful.

Comment: The SVD of a matrix expresses it as a sum of outer products. Outer product is also defined for tensors, so why not.

Answer (score 1):

What you have found is a [tensor rank decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition), which is something that the SVD gives you for $2$-tensors. In this way, your decomposition can indeed be thought of as a generalization of the SVD. In fact, what you get is the same thing that you would get by applying the ["higher order SVD" algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition). See the [interpretation section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition#Interpretation) of that second page for details.